# About preventing bubbling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I would like to ask if there are any ways to prevent the event bubbling out from the "li"s. Below is my code, Thanks!

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    var currentArticle=$("li.current");
    var nextArticle=currentArticle.next();
    var prevArticle=currentArticle.prev();

    switch(event.which){
        case 40:
            currentArticle.removeClass("current");
            nextArticle.addClass("current");
            break;
        case 38:
            currentArticle.removeClass("current");
            prevArticle.addClass("current");
            break;
        case 79:
            currentArticle.find(".description").toggle();
            break;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery documentation and you will find [`event#stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.